# Correct way to manually add a xib file

Tags: objective-c

What is the correct way to manually add a xib file i.e. if while creating the class, we uncheck "With XIB for interface"...then how do we connect both the IB & VC.m file later, to ensure that the view gets loaded from xib ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically this is done when you instantiate your sub-classed UIViewController. Your call would look something like this:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] 
                                       initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
```

Checkout [UIViewController initWithNibName: bundle:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a) documentation for more details. You can also look at the [documentation on Custom View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101) for a good bit of information on sub-classing UIViewControllers.

Answer (score 1):

To allow setting actions and outlets at design time in IB, once you create the xib file, change File Owner to your controller class. To do this, in IB, with File Owner selected, press Command-4.

Comment: Your comment helped me a lot.